# Integral of volume

Tags: math-mode

How i can correct the positioning of the limits of this integral
[image]

i would an effect like this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\iiint \limits_{-\infty\ -\infty\ -\infty}
    ^{\ \ \ +\infty\ +\infty\ +\infty} 
    \psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)\, dr\,d\theta\,d\phi

\end{document}
```

i have found the code below what do you think about it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)\, dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=1
\end{equation}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand where you want them to begin with.

Comment: Could you please put that code into an MWE so we can just copy paste it? Even better would be to also add a picture of your equation.

Comment: I would skip the limits and just put the domain of integration as: `\iiint \limits_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}\psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)\, dr\,d\theta\,d\phi`. and change the integral to volume integral

Comment: This is a comment about the content of your formula rather than about its representation using TeX: the limits of integration should *not* be the real numbers but (i) `[0,\infty]` for the radius `r` and (ii) `[0,2\pi]` for the two angles `$\theta$` and `$\phi$`.

Comment: thanks why only from 0 to infty for the radius ?

Comment: because in a system of a spherical coordinates there is not negative part rigth?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use separate `\int\limits...` for each one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Original:
\[
    \iiint \limits_{-\infty\ -\infty\ -\infty}^{+\infty\ +\infty\ +\infty} \psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)\, dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=1
\]
Separate:
\[
    \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)\, dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=1
\]
\end{document}
```

In my experience the `\iint` and `\iiint` are more useful when you are specifying the region of integration using a local definition- this is what Percusse mentioned in his comment (permission given to post in chat)

[image]

```
\[
    \iiint \limits_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}}\psi_{nlm}(r,\theta,\phi)\, dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=1
\]
```

On another note, you might like to use `\mathrm{d}` for the `d` in each integration.

Comment: good i have found also the code that i have added in my question, what do you think about it?

Comment: @FormlessCloud should be equivalent

Comment: the distance between integrals is bigger with my code...

Comment: @FormlessCloud perhaps it's the `\limits` that makes the difference